# UFW firewall deny incoming connections except for one ip

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, port, ufw

I want to deny all incoming connections to port 6677 except for one ip-address (so it can only be reached from a docker container running on the host, the port should not be accessible from "outside").
Everything else should be allowed (ufw default allow outgoing, ufw default allow incoming).
How can I do this with UFW firewall?

With nftables I did something like this:
ip saddr != 172.19.0.2 tcp dport 6677 drop

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use `ufw allow from 172.19.0.2 to any port 6677`

But as far as I know, whenever you launch the docker container it runs on a different IP unless you fix the IP.

Comment: Thank you this worked. I used the IP with a subnet, this way it works even if the IP changes.

Comment: I had forgotten to use the IP with subnet, now that you said it I remember that I already did that.